# Catching 4 details tags present in the DOM and identifying them as one

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an application that displays data on dropdowns of details tag. Sometimes these details tags are doubled or tripled depending on how much data that is coming from the db. eg, If the detail tags are 4, it means only one party is involved. If they are 8 details tags, it means two parties are involved. I want to be able to display the number of parties as to the number of details tags that appears on the DOM.

```
  .html
  <details id="party">
    <summary class="sub-header-style-1 pt-3 mb-4">
    Applicant(s) Information - {{ party.organization }} {{ party.firstName }} {{ 
    party.lastName }}
  </summary>
  </details>
```

[image: party indication]

Comment: Can you create a stackbiltz demo with dummy data

Comment: This is the link to the stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-juorxg?file=src%2Fapp%2F

Comment: Isn't there a loop to load the details based on data retrieved from the db

Comment: There is a loop that loads dynamic data from db. Sometimes the details and summary tags are doubled or tripled

Comment: Yes, you have to add that to the demo

Comment: I have added that to the demo, please you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `parties.length`

`<h2>({{parties.length}}) Party(s)</h2>`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkzc6j?file=src/app/app.component.html)